# Would Turbo C and the executables generated by Turbo C compilations run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ms-dos, x86, 16-bit

For some reason I have Turbo C compiler (DOS version). I believe both the Turbo C executable and the C programs compiled into executables are 16-bit versions. I have a Windows 7 system. Would like to know -

1. Will the Turbo C executable work on x64 Windows 7.
2. Would the executables obtained by compiling C code in Turbo C be able to execute on x64 Windows 7?
3. Setting what option in the "Compatibility" setting of that *.exe properties would enable that 16-bit code above to run properly,or something more is needed?

Comment: [Is it possible to run 16 bit code in an operating system that supports Intel IA-32e mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21798325/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can run 16bit programs on windows 7 64 bit directly, but you might be able to run it in a [dos emulator](http://www.dosbox.com/) or in windows XP mode.  Some of the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/15631/why-do-i-need-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) indicate that you might be able to do what you want in XP mode, if your version of windows 7 supports it.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application) and its answers for why the 64 bit os can't run 16 bit programs

Comment: Get DOSBOX and everything will be fine.